# Copiar dos objetos en c++

Tags: c++

Estoy desarrollando un `script` el cual consiste en una biblioteca que almacena libros (que son los objetos del código). Me gustaría crear una función que se llame *Libro*, su función principal será copiar dos libros, pero no lo consigo. La función es `Libro::copiarLibro()`, aparece al final de el archivo llamado Libro.h:

Dejo el código:
Libro.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#ifndef LIBRO_H_
#define LIBRO_H_

using namespace std;

class Libro {

public:
    Libro();
    Libro (string t, string au, string gen, int num);
    Libro(string lineafich);

    virtual ~Libro();

    string  generarTejuelo();
    void setTejuelo();

    string getTitulo();
    void setTitulo(string titulo);

    string getAutor();
    void setAutor(string autor);

    string getGenero();
    void setGenero(string genero);

    int getNumPaginas();
    void setNumPaginas(int numPaginas);

    string aCadena();
    string formatoFichero();

    bool tieneDatos();
    Libro copiarLibro();

private:
    string titulo;
    string autor;
    string  genero;
    string tejuelo;
    int numPaginas;
};
```

Libro.cpp

```
Libro Libro:: copiarLibro(){
    Libro l1, l2;
    l2 = l1;
    return l2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes la función `CopiarLibro()` dentro de las funciones públicas, lo que "ata" a la instancia actual de la clase `Libro` a copiar solo ese libro.

Para hacerlo mas global, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
Libro* copiarLibro(Libro *from)
{
    Libro *rtn = new Libro(from->titulo, from->autor, /* otros parametros... */);
    return rtn;
}
```

En tu código, lo que haces básicamente es definir 2 libros nuevos, cuyo valor aún no se define, y asignas una referencia `NULL` de `l2` a `l1`, y no devuelve nada.

De la forma como lo puse, defines 2 variables libro, yo usé la siguiente clase para pruebas:

```
class Libro
{
    public:
        Libro(string);
        string Nombre;
};
Libro::Libro(string s)
{
    Nombre = s;
}
```

Y la función que te he puesto arriba para copiarlo:

```
Libro* copiarLibro(Libro *from)
{
    Libro *rtn = new Libro(from->Nombre);
    return rtn;
}
```

Resultando este el método main:

```
int main()
{
    Libro *L1 = new Libro("Historias Chinas del 91");
    cout << "Nombre actual de L1: " << L1->Nombre << "\n"; // Imprime: Historias Chinas del 91.
    Libro *L2 = copiarLibro(L1);
    L1->Nombre = "Cuentos Nacionales"; // Le asigno el valor de otro nombre a L1.
    cout << "Nombre de L1: " << L1->Nombre << "\n";
    cout << "Nombre de L2: " << L2->Nombre << "\n"; 

    return 0;
}
```

Mostrando como resultado lo siguiente:

```
Nombre Actual de L1: Historias Chinas del 91
Nombre de L1: Cuentos Nacionales
Nombre de L2: Historias Chinas del 91
```

Básicamente, vas a copiar una instancia de un libro `A` en otro libro `B`, para tener el mismo libro en 2 variables distintas.

---

**EDIT:** No he entendido vien cual es la función de `CopiarLibro()` exactamente, pero como tu comentario menciona que la función no puede tener parámetros, entonces creo que entiendo el sentido de que la función esté dentro de la clase.

En ese caso, usa la misma función que tiene tu clase `Libro` y agrega lo siguiente al prototipo:

```
public:
    Libro *CopiarLibro(); // El prototipo.
```

Y en su definición:

```
Libro *Libro::CopiarLibro()
{
    Libro *L = new Libro(this->Nombre /* , otros parámetros. */);
    return L;
}
```

Y probemos un nuevo método `main()`:

```
int main() 
{
    Libro *ViejoLibro = new Libro("La biblia");
    cout << "El viejo libro: " << ViejoLibro->Nombre << "\n\n";

    Libro *NuevoLibro = ViejoLibro->CopiarLibro();
    cout << "El nuevo libro:" << NuevoLibro->Nombre << "\n";

    ViejoLibro->Nombre = "Vacio"; // Asignamos "vacio" como nombre del libro.
    cout << "El viejo libro: " << ViejoLibro->Nombre << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Dando el siguiente resultado:

```
El viejo libro: La biblia

El nuevo libro:La biblia
El viejo libro: Vacio
```

Espero que te haya ayudado!

Comment: Es una solución muy satisfactoria, lo que pasa es que la función no puede tener parámetros. Ese es mi problema, no sé muy bien cómo encajarla sin parámetros.

Comment: @DDenche mira el editado, se adapta a tu situación actual.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, para empezar en tu función copiar libro lo único que estás haciendo es crear una instancia de la clase libro vacía y después copias su contenido en otra instancia también vacía, con lo cual obtienes como retorno una instancia vacía.

Para lograr tu objetivo lo puedes hacer de distintas maneras aquí te dejare 2 de ejemplo:

## 1.- Función dentro de la clase

Libro.h:

```
class Libro
{
   ...//constructor, destructor, variables y metodos
public:
   void copiarLibro(const Libro& copia);
}
```

Libro.cpp:

```
void Libro::copiarLibro(const Libro& copia){
   *this = copia;
}
```

## 2.- Función exterior

Libro.h:

```
void copiarLibro(const Libro& from,Libro& to);
```

Libro.cpp

```
void copiarLibro(const Libro& from, Libro& to){
   to = from;
}
```

Por ultimo no olvides que también podrías simplemente copiar los contenidos directamente desde tu función principal.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

   Libro A("Cuento de Terror","Autor","Terror",240)
   Libro B;
   B = A;

   //o bien con el método miembro
   B.copiarLibro(A);

   return 0;
}
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad :)